# Flash on Ubuntu server 12.10 for Firefox

Tags: flash

What is a clean way to install Flash on ubuntu server 12.10? The package flashplugin-installer doesn't seem to be available any more. Is it no longer packaged? Or would I need to do something like step 3 in https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player even though that seems to be for Ubuntu Desktop edition, not Ubuntu Server.

This is for incorporation with Firefox for testing.

Comment: i'm pretty sure Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server use the same repos, and are the same operating system. they are just different packages for installation media. maybe this should be on askubuntu?

Comment: [ubuntu.se] does not permit questions about end of life Ubuntu versions. As for the linked question, I would suggest reading more than the first answer.